# Unit test cases for web sockets using akka http

Tags: scala, unit-testing, websocket, akka, akka-http

I have implemented web sockets using Akka HTTP. I am consuming data from Kafka and sending notifications using web sockets. Functionality is working fine but **I am stuck in test cases**.

```
 ` private def loginNotificationRoute(): Route = {
    cors() {
      pathPrefix("notifications" / Segment) { userName =>
        get {
          handleWebSocketMessages(notificationClientFlow(userName))
        }
      }
    }
  }`
```

Notification Actor reads notifications from database and sends data back to client.

```
`  def notificationClientFlow(userName: String): Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed] = {
    info(s"Connection Request accepted for user $userName")
    val notificationActor = actorSystem.actorOf(NotificationActor.props(userName, jsonHelper))

    val incomingMessages: Sink[Message, NotUsed] =
      Flow[Message].map {
        case TextMessage.Strict(text) => NotificationActor.IncomingMessage(text)
      }.to(Sink.actorRef(notificationActor, PoisonPill))

    val outgoingMessages: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
      Source
        .actorRef[NotificationActor.ResponseType](BUFFER_SIZE, OverflowStrategy.fail)
        .mapMaterializedValue { outgoingActor =>
          notificationActor ! NotificationActor.Connected(outgoingActor)
          NotUsed
        }
        .map {
          notificationResponse: NotificationActor.ResponseType =>
            info(s"sending notification ${notificationResponse.action}")
            TextMessage.Strict(jsonHelper.write(notificationResponse))
        }

    Flow.fromSinkAndSource(incomingMessages, outgoingMessages)
  }`
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: How to write unit test cases of loginNotificationRoute()  and notificationClientFlow(userName: String) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Re-Design Of Dependencies**

In my opinion the biggest drawback to your current design is that there is an inherent dependency on a specific `actorSystem`; the offending line of code being

```
//actorSystem comes from the outside world!!!
val notificationActor = actorSystem.actorOf(NotificationActor.props(userName, jsonHelper))
```

The `notificationClientFlow` method should be re-parameterized so that all dependencies are explicitly listed in the argument.  And there shouldn't be a dependency on an entire `ActorSystem`, instead it should be reduced to just an `ActorRef`:

```
def notificationClientFlow(userName: String, 
                           notificationActor : ActorRef): Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed] = {
  //notificationActor is now passed in
  //val notificationActor = actorSystem.actorOf(NotificationActor.props(userName, jsonHelper))
}
```

This would require a similar explicit declaration in the `Route` creating method:

```
private def loginNotificationRoute(notificationActor : ActorRef)() : Route = {
  ...
  handleWebSocketMessages(notificationClientFlow(userName, notificationActor))
}
```

**Testing**

Now the testing can be achieved using [`TestKit`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/testing.html#asynchronous-testing-testkit):

```
class MySpec() extends TestKit(ActorSystem("MySpec")) {

  val userName = "testUser"

  val notificationActor = 
    system.actorOf(NotificationActor.props(userName, jsonHelper))

  val testFlow = notificationClientFlow(userName, notificationActor)

}
```

Also, because we've explicitly passed the `ActorRef` and not just the `ActorSystem` we can use other advanced testing features like [probes](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/testing.html#overriding-behavior):

```
val probe = TestProbe()

val testProbeFlow = notificationClientFlow(userName, probe.ref)
```

The above technique would similarly apply to testing the Route using [standard techniques](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/testkit.html):

```
val testRoute = loginNotificationRoute(testProbe)

Get() ~> testRoute() ~> check {
  //testing assertions here
}
```